# Rotate specific images from list in RMagick

Tags: r

I want to process a large number of images, some of them need to be rotated as they are horizontal. How can I subset a "magick-image" object based on image width?

```
test = list.files(path = "D:/Pictures/", pattern = "*.jpg", full.names = T)[1:12] %>% image_read

test
# A tibble: 12 x 7
   format width height colorspace matte filesize density
   <chr>  <int>  <int> <chr>      <lgl>    <int> <chr>  
 1 JPEG    3968   2976 sRGB       FALSE  3795426 72x72  
 2 JPEG    3968   2976 sRGB       FALSE  2571222 72x72  
 3 JPEG    3968   2976 sRGB       FALSE  3330400 72x72  
 4 JPEG    3968   2976 sRGB       FALSE  3406587 72x72  
 5 JPEG    3968   2976 sRGB       FALSE  2822574 72x72  
 6 JPEG    3968   2976 sRGB       FALSE  3099068 72x72  
 7 JPEG    3968   2976 sRGB       FALSE  2954393 72x72  
 8 JPEG    3968   2976 sRGB       FALSE  4082813 72x72  
 9 JPEG    3968   2976 sRGB       FALSE  3734903 72x72  
10 JPEG    3968   2976 sRGB       FALSE  3610711 72x72  
11 JPEG    2976   3968 sRGB       FALSE  2749896 72x72  
12 JPEG    2976   3968 sRGB       FALSE  3421131 72x72  

test[test$width>test$height]
Error in test$width : object of type 'externalptr' is not subsettable

test %>% dplyr::filter(width > height)
Error in UseMethod("filter") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "magick-image"
```

I can do it with the image_info()

```
test %>% image_info %>% dplyr::filter(width > height)
# A tibble: 10 x 7
   format width height colorspace matte filesize density
   <chr>  <int>  <int> <chr>      <lgl>    <int> <chr>  
 1 JPEG    3968   2976 sRGB       FALSE  3795426 72x72  
 2 JPEG    3968   2976 sRGB       FALSE  2571222 72x72  
 3 JPEG    3968   2976 sRGB       FALSE  3330400 72x72  
 4 JPEG    3968   2976 sRGB       FALSE  3406587 72x72  
 5 JPEG    3968   2976 sRGB       FALSE  2822574 72x72  
 6 JPEG    3968   2976 sRGB       FALSE  3099068 72x72  
 7 JPEG    3968   2976 sRGB       FALSE  2954393 72x72  
 8 JPEG    3968   2976 sRGB       FALSE  4082813 72x72  
 9 JPEG    3968   2976 sRGB       FALSE  3734903 72x72  
10 JPEG    3968   2976 sRGB       FALSE  3610711 72x72
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a function that conditionally rotates an image based on whether its width is greater than its length, and then map this across your list:

```
 library(magick)
 library(purrr)

 rotate_img <- function(img) {
  if (image_info(img)$width > image_info(img)$height) {
    return(image_rotate(img, 90))
  } else {
    return(img)
  }
}

test <- map(test, ~ rotate_img(.))
```